Using "Google Coral Dev Board" as a "local runtime" on "Google Colab"
I am unable to route Jupyter Notebook from Google Coral Dev Board to my Local Machine (Windows 10) Google Colab.
The message says:
bind [127.0.0.1]:8888: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888
Could not request local forwarding.


I was following this guide by Google on "Running Google Colab on Coral Dev Board" (https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-coral/tutorials/blob/master/run_colab_on_devboard.ipynb).
According to this, I started Jupyter Notebook on Coral Dev Board using port 8888.
This is what I executed:
mendel@king-tang:~$ jupyter notebook \
>   --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
>   --port=8888 \
>   --NotebookApp.port_retries=0

jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized.
Listening on /http_over_websocket
[I 20:09:10.166 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/mendel
[I 20:09:10.166 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.7 is running at:
[I 20:09:10.167 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8c376ee3de463c41fbc280bd3c5c6dd61fff2d91b758a9fa
[I 20:09:10.167 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=8c376ee3de463c41fbc280bd3c5c6dd61fff2d91b758a9fa
[I 20:09:10.167 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 20:09:10.185 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 20:09:10.186 NotebookApp]
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
file:///home/mendel/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-6309-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost:8888/?token=8c376ee3de463c41fbc280bd3c5c6dd61fff2d91b758a9fa
or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=8c376ee3de463c41fbc280bd3c5c6dd61fff2d91b758a9fa
AFTER THAT.
I executed this in another terminal:
mendel@king-tang:~$ ssh -N -L 8888:localhost:8888 mendel@192.168.101.2 -i ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key
Enter passphrase for key '/home/mendel/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key':
bind [127.0.0.1]:8888: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888
Could not request local forwarding.

Also, unable to connect to localhost which is obvious.
[http://localhost:8888](https://i.sstatic.net/tr0dq3Oy.png)
